# How to find fixed lengths of multidimensional arrays by assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, multidimensional-array, reverse-engineering

How do you go about solving the fixed constants of an array if you have 3 dimensions? I can compute that the assembly code gets us the formula 
((32k + j)16 + i) in %rax for indexing array2 and
((32i + j)16 + k) in %rdx for indexing array1, but how does this help use find the constants M, N and L?

```
#define M ___________
#define N ____________
#define L ____________

int array1[M][N][L];
int array2[L][N][M];

int copyandsub(int i, int j, int k){
    array1[i][j][k] = array2[k][j][i] - 1;
}
```

Assembly code generated:

```
Copandsub:
movslq %edi, %rdi
movslq %edx, %rdx
movslq %esi, %rsi
movq %rdx, %rax
salq $5, %rax
addq %rsi, %rax
salq $4, %rax
addq %rdi, %rax
movl array2(,%rax,4), %eax
subl $1, %eax
salq $5, %rdi
addq %rdi, %rsi
salq $4, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rdx
movl %eax, array1(,%rdx,4)
ret
```

Comment: It should be obvious. If you look at each array individually, you should know the size of the last two dimensions, but not the first dimension.

Comment: Which numbers correspond with M,N and L? K matches with L for array 2 and we have 32 as our factor. But the answer is apparently M = 16, N = 32 and L = 16. I just don't know how to connect the values to the right constants.

Comment: `array1` is an MxNxL array. `array1[0]` is an NxL array, `array1[0][0]` is an array of length L, `array1[0][0][0]` is a single `int`.

Comment: those arrays are in memory as consecutive area of (M * N * L * 4) bytes. The inner dimension is usually byte by byte, so first (L * 4) bytes for `array1` is reserved for L `int`s. The byte offset of `array1[0][1][0]`, ie. first value on second row, is right after it: L*4. The byte offset of `array1[1][0][0]` is N*L*4. So from `((32i + j)16 + k)` (int index, not byte offset) you can see you have to do i*32*16 in ints, ie. the inner two dimensions have size 32*16. And from the 16*j you can deduct the inner dimension of the two has size 16. The mirror nature of (i,j,k) vs (k,j,i) enforces M == L.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
int arrayTest[2][3][4];
// = technically equivalent of int flatArray[2*3*4]; for compiler
// That's how rest of the C++ compiled code will address it

for (auto m = 0; m < 2; ++m)
    for (auto n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
        for (auto l = 0; l < 4; ++l)
            arrayTest[m][n][l] = m*100 + n*10 + l;
// value of each cell looks like "mnl" (ie arrayTest[1][2][0] == 120)
```

Then the array memory looks like this [value (showing trio-indices)] (index into "flatArray"):

```
[000] ( 0) [001] ( 1) [002] ( 2) [003] ( 3) 
[010] ( 4) [011] ( 5) [012] ( 6) [013] ( 7) 
[020] ( 8) [021] ( 9) [022] (10) [023] (11) 
[100] (12) [101] (13) [102] (14) [103] (15) 
[110] (16) [111] (17) [112] (18) [113] (19) 
[120] (20) [121] (21) [122] (22) [123] (23)
```

where "flattened" index is `i = m*3*4 + n*4 + l;`.

Also note that's how the memory content looks, row by row, ie in hex dwords it's:
`00000000 00000001 00000002 00000003 0000000A 0000000B 0000000C 0000000D 00000014 00000015 ...` (0xA = "010" in decimal).

So you have to understand how that "flattened" index works, then your " ((32k + j)16 + i)" and "((32i + j)16 + k)" gives enough information to figure out original M, N, L.